# Like button & open graph tags within canvas app

Tags: html, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

So...

I made a canvas app and now I would like to create a like button for it.

My first idea was, just create a like button with data-href HTML parameter set to https://apps.facebook.com/my_awesome_app and place that button somewhere on the index page. Cool...

Well it is working but now quite as I intended. Activity is described like this... {name} likes {object which is in this case my app} on {app_name}. And I do not want that, it looks silly. I simply want {name} likes {app_name}

So I googled and stacked for couple of hours and came to a vague conclusion - OG tags.

I have been fiddling for some time now, and i had absolutely no luck. Help me out.

Cheers!

Comment: noone? really? this can't be uncommon.

Comment: I'm looking for this as well. Did you get anywhere with the OG tags? I'm pretty certain it will be og:type but I haven't started experimenting yet. My issue was that if I used the app URL as you have the users who liked it didn't see posts to the community page that it generated for me.